# I don't want some entries to show up in my table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

[image]

as seen in the image above, I don't want the last two entries, i.e. facebook and twitter, to show in my table and only want an entry that have user id. How can i avoid this situation. Please don't mind my vocabularies as I do not have rich programming vocabulary.

I am using this code in the database

```
SELECT users.id, EXTRACT(YEAR from AGE(users.dob)) AS Age, users.gender, users.nationality as Country, app.name AS App 
    FROM users
    FULL OUTER JOIN app_user_profile
        ON users.id = app_user_profile.users_id
    FULL OUTER JOIN app
        ON app_user_profile.app_id = app.id
ORDER BY users.id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using FULL OUTER JOIN, you should use LEFT OUTER JOIN aka LEFT JOIN, or If you really want to exact match  from `users`,`app_user_profile` and `app` relations, then use strict join i,e `INNER JOIN` aka `JOIN`

try either this

```
SELECT users.id,
       EXTRACT(YEAR
               FROM AGE(users.dob)) AS Age,
       users.gender,
       users.nationality AS Country,
       app.name AS App
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN app_user_profile ON users.id = app_user_profile.users_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN app ON app_user_profile.app_id = app.id
ORDER BY users.id;
```

OR

```
SELECT users.id,
       EXTRACT(YEAR
               FROM AGE(users.dob)) AS Age,
       users.gender,
       users.nationality AS Country,
       app.name AS App
FROM users
INNER JOIN app_user_profile ON users.id = app_user_profile.users_id
INNER JOIN app ON app_user_profile.app_id = app.id
ORDER BY users.id;
```